# Visual Studio 2012. "unable to start program" *.exe "cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Yes, I know this is a common question. No other question/answer sets meet my needs here. Taking c++ this quarter. Been going along just fine. Trying to do last assignment, and I'm getting the above error, even on a fresh project with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world" << endl;
}
```

As an experiment, I tried pasting in much more elaborate code from previous assignments. This runs. Just pasting in -- not running the previous assignment.

I took the simplest of them, and stripped it down to this:

Main.cpp:

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   double hours, rate;

   cout << "Hello World";
   cin >> hours;

   cout << "Hello World";
   cin >> rate;

   system("pause");

   return 0; 
}
```

This compiles and runs fine. However, if I remove either of the `cin` lines I get the error stated in the title.

I'm just flabbergasted because pasted in code compiles and runs, but even "Hello World" in a fresh project won't.

Does my above example provide any clues?

Comment: You need to pay attention to build errors, don't blindly press F5 when the build failed.  If you are 100% sure that there were no errors then you surely lost the battle with your anti-malware.  They tend to get a wedgie when an EXE appears from nowhere.  Make an exclusion for your projects folder, get rid of it completely if it is Avast.

Answer (score -2):

Does it happen if you run it as administrator? Were you running it from Visual Studio or did you clicked the executable?

If you have an anti virus, it may be causing the error as well.

Comment: This should really be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I just hit the green run arrow in the menu ;) I'm a coddled VS programmer. Something deeply strange is going on with how VS is creating new projects.